# Why VLC runs “proxy” command when it is directed to some internet stream?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

I have an executable file in my PATH which is named “proxy”.

I open VLC, open http://176.31.123.212:8192/ and VLC runs the “proxy” passing http://176.31.123.212:8192/ as its argument and waits something from it. Why does VLC do it and how to disable it?